# Confusing about bash "$()" and then new line character

Tags: bash

Looks like the trailing `'\n'` character is trimmed with the form `"$()",` while I can't find any specification about this from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). It is really confusing, anyone could help me explain this?

```
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ a="$(echo $'abc\n\n' | cat)"
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo "$a"
abc
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ a="$(echo $'abc\n\nb' | cat)"
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo "$a"
abc

b
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ a=$'abc\n'
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo "$a"
abc

[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ a="$(echo $'abc  ' | cat)"
[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$ echo "$a" | url_encode
abc%20%20%0A[roxma@VM_6_207_centos ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I just found the explanation from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, `with any
>   trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted`, but they
>   may be removed during word splitting. The command substitution $(cat
>   file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).